# React Axios with UseEffect not rendering data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have been struggling myself silly to get data read from a local json file and fed into a React render function. I first read the code in via a class through the `componentDidMount` method, but the data always arrived later than the render function executed. I have looked at a number of solutions. Most people seem to recommend the use of `useEffect` and `useState` to get around this issue.

This is what I have so far:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

export default function Foo() {
    const [list, setProjects] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('data.json')
            .then(response => {
                setProjects(response.data)
            })
    }, [])

    console.log(list);
    debugger;

    if (list !== null) {
        return (
            <div>
                Project: {/*{list.projects[0].title}*/}
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                Loading Project Data ...
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The incoming data comes in the format `{"projects" : [{"id": 1, "title": "some title", ...}, ... {...}]}`.

Issue is, even though I have a null check wrapping around the return, the code always jumps into the first branch, and complains that there is nothing (nothing is shown with `Project: {list}` and `Project: {list.projects[0].title}` errors because list is deemed to be null). The console shows the data loading, but I suspect there is an async issue at play related to the promise. I have tuned the initial state, but no luck so far.

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Thank you to all the replies received. Whilst they helped to streamline the code and added extra checks, I still had the same issue with the data not being displayed. It seems the problem lay with the initial value I assigned. I changed these to:

`const [list, setProjects] = useState({projects: [{title: "XXX"}]});`

And the code worked fine. I guess this dummy value gets overwritten by the actual json vales once these became available.

Comment: So if you put `console.log(response.data)` immediately after `.then(response => {`, what do you see in the console?

Comment: Tuning initial state isn't the answer. So how is what you're doing structurally different from this: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-butterfly-mtto5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Is this JSON file ***IN*** your app's source directory? Why not just import it? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-axios-with-useeffect-not-rendering-data-enqyb

Answer (score 1):

**try create another state**

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        axios.get('data.json')
            .then(response => {
                setProjects(response.data);
                setLoading(false);
            })
    }, [])

 if (loading) {

else{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using another variable isLoading, when the axios works to fetch the data set it to true and the after the response set it to False. Try the following code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

export default function Foo() {
    const [list, setProjects] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
       setIsLoading(true);
       axios.get('data.json')
         .then(response => {
           setProjects(response.data);
           setIsLoading(false);
                    })
         }, []);
console.log(list);
debugger;
return (
<React.Fragment>
{isLoading && <h1>Loading Data.........</h1>}
{!isLoading && (<div> Project: {/*{list.projects[0].title}*/}</div>)}
</React.Fragment>
);
}
```

Comment: When you try to change the appearance with the data, that is being Loaded dynamically, the render function simply takes only the previous data. So, it is always better to work with another variable that will be changed when the data is fully loaded, make sure it's a boolean, like I have used the isLoading. The change the visual based on this boolean, not based on the data, that will be loaded dynamicaly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
if (list !== null) {
    return (
        <div>
            Project: {/*{list.projects[0].title}*/}
        </div>
    )
} else {
    return (
        <div>
            Loading Project Data ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

I would do something like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    {list && list.projects && list.projects.length > 0 ? (
      <p>{list.projects[0].title}</p>
    ) : (
      <p>Loading Project Data...</p>
    )}      
  </div>
);
```